# (In brief) How it works?

Tags: c, buffer, system-calls

**Hi everyone**
**I need your help**

I'm Zed, and i have a primitiv question, look at this function :

```
void    cat_stdin(void)
{
    char    c[1] //c;

    while (read(0, c//&c, 1) > 0)
         write(1, c//&c, 1);
}
```

how it works ? what are doing write and read syscall ?
this code is like : cat -

Sorry i'm a french noob

Share your knowledge to me, i'm stuck :/

Comment: the file descriptor 0 is stdin, and the file descriptor 1 is stdout. So, while read from stdin returns a positive number the program writes whatever is read back to stdout.

Comment: there is a hidden buffer ? cuz when i write 'aaaa\n' it writes 'aaaa\n' but buffer is a char of size 1

Comment: It *doesn't* work.  It does not even compile.  I see some possible modifications that would make it compilable, but we prefer not to guess about such things.

Comment: You are correct. Your buffer (i.e. `c`) is length 1. So, each `read` gets one `char`. And, each `write` outputs one `char`. But, because it's in the `while` loop, which keeps looping as long as `read` has more data, it outputs the _entire_ amount of data, one char/byte at a time.

Comment: It's part of a program @John Bollinger

Comment: Note that your posted code won't compile because of the _embedded_ ANSI style comments (e.g. `//`). To compile cleanly, change `c//&c` into just `c`. Or, use K&R style comments: `c//&c` --> `c/*&c*/`. ANSI comments are sometimes easier to deal with, but _everything_ in the comment [to the end of the line] is treated as a comment. So, `char c[1] //c;` --> `char c[1]; // this is the 'c' variable`

Comment: Please note that this is insanely inefficient.  Suppose you need to carry grains of sand up to the 20th floor in a building with no elevator.  You can climb the stairs for each individual grain of sand (which is what this code is doing), or you can wait until you have 2 Kg of sand and make the trip just once.  Use `fread` and `fwrite`.

Comment: c is reallocated during the loop ? so *write()* writes after *read()* encouter '\n' ?

Comment: `c` is _not_ "reallocated" [or even _allocated_--as in memory from the heap via `malloc`, which the program is _not_ doing]. It is in the same place on each loop iteration [in it's assigned place in the stack frame for the `main` function]

Comment: Where the entire amount of data is stocked ? @ Craig Estey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posted answer has a few issues.

Notably, `cat_stdout` and `cat_stdin` could be one function (e.g. `cat_stream`) that takes the input file descriptor as an argument.

It's only transferring one byte at a time, so it's very slow.

Here's a version that I coded from scratch [with annotations]. It handles most cases and has error checking. It may help you improve your own version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int
cat_stream(int fd)
{
    ssize_t rlen;
    ssize_t wlen;
    int err = 0;
    char *cur;
    char buf[64 * 1024];

    // NOTE: the buffer size can be _any_ length, but 64KB is optimal for many
    // filesystem files or devices

    while (1) {
        // read a chunk of input
        rlen = read(fd,buf,sizeof(buf));

        // end of file
        if (rlen == 0)
            break;

        // error
        if (rlen < 0) {
            err = errno;
            fprintf(stderr,"cat_stream: read error -- %s\n",strerror(err));
            break;
        }

        // write out all data read in current chunk -- loop until all data
        // read in this chunk has been output, even if it could _not_ be
        // output in a single write call, advancing the pointer into the
        // buffer [and shortening the remaining length]
        cur = buf;
        for (;  rlen > 0;  rlen -= wlen, cur += wlen) {
            wlen = write(1,cur,rlen);

            // handle error
            if (wlen < 0) {
                err = errno;
                fprintf(stderr,"cat_stream: write error -- %s\n",strerror(err));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // restore errno after fprintf so caller can use it [if desired]
    if (err)
        errno = err;

    return err;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    const char *file;
    int fd;
    int err = 0;

    // skip over program name
    --argc;
    ++argv;

    // no arguments means stdin -- fake a "-" entry
    if (argc <= 0) {
        ++argc;
        --argv;
        argv[0] = "-";
    }

    // loop on all input files
    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        file = *argv;

        // copy stdin
        if (strcmp(file,"-") == 0) {
            cat_stream(0);
            continue;
        }

        // open the explicit input file
        fd = open(file,O_RDONLY);
        if (fd < 0) {
            err = errno;
            fprintf(stderr,"cat: unable to open '%s' -- %s\n",
                file,strerror(err));
            break;
        }

        // cat the open file stream
        err = cat_stream(fd);

        // close the input file
        close(fd);

        // stop on error
        if (err)
            break;
    }

    // regardless of the error, just return 1
    if (err)
        err = 1;

    return err;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate, i am still learning but in my case, which is bad and very slow, where the amount of data is stocked ? thats my only problem ... i dont figure out the mechanism

Comment: Not to worry, it gets [will get] easier--I promise ;-) I realize English may not be your first language, so when you say: _where the amount of data is stocked?_, do you mean where the data is _stored_ in memory? That is [based on your earlier comments], I'm guessing you're having trouble with the concept of the program's stack frame? Or, how the _length_ of the `read/write` is specified [the amount of data to transfer]? I may be able to edit my answer with additional explanation that may help if you can further explain what you're having trouble with.